# Set the color of an event when adding it to the calendar

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

How do I set the color of an event that I [add programmatically](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event) to the android native calendar?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might have to use googles [api java client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) instead of using the calendar provider.

This way you'll not use the phones android api but instead go directly to the source (googles calendar api). You'll update the calendar online which again will update the phones calendar automatically. The biggest problem is that the solution gets more complex since you wont just use the native android library but you'll be able to do more this way. Also you'll be able to make your features to phones before api 14.

Comment: Well that seems like overkill just to change a color . But thanks.

Comment: If color isn't directly supported by calendar provider this is probably the only way to go =/ I agree its completely overkill if you only want to make something simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to set the color of a particular event android.

And the only way seems to be to set the color of the calendar and that can only be done from the web interface of google calendar

Comment: omg.... no solutions for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are working with ICS and above. You can change/add colour to your event if you are working as a sync adapter

For reference read here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html